# Which preposition should go first? "for two hours" or "to her"?

Tags: prepositions, present-perfect-progressive

Which preposition should go first? "for two hours" or "for her"? and why?

> He has been writing a letter **for two hours** to her.

> He has been writing a letter **to her** for two hours.

Comment: I can understand both sentences, but the first one is confusing. This error is called a misplaced modifier. Does he write a letter for a person named "two hours"?, it's quite ridiculous right. The second sentence is OK.

Comment: Normally we write letters _to_ people, not _for_ them. I wouldn't go so far as to say "for her" is incorrect, but I do think this could be improved by saying: _For two hours, he has been writing a letter to her._

Comment: Shouldn't it be *since* two hours?

Comment: @CinCout - No, but it could be: _He has been writing a letter to her since two hours **ago**_.

Comment: @J.R. I am sure you are wrong about this one. *ago* is not required; *since* itself gives the starting point of actions, events or states. It refers to when things began.

Comment: @CinCout "since two hours" without "ago" is invalid. *Since* indicates a starting *point* when an event happens, while *two hours* implies a period.

Comment: As a native speaker the word since looks and sounds very out of place in this sentence. Usually, using since is with a set time, so I understand where the 'ago' is coming from, but it would be better to use since with a more general time, 'since this morning' is a perfect example, 'since two hours ago' is something that I've never really heard a native speaker ever say.

Comment: *"He has been writing a letter to her since two hours"* is correct. So is *"He started writing a letter to her two hours ago"*. But I fail to understand how *since* and *ago* will come together as pointed out by @J.R.

Comment: If you really want to emphasize the "two hours", than put that in front: "For two hours he has been writing a letter to her. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as people have pointed out in the comments "writing a letter to her" is much more natural than "writing a letter for her" [The question has already been edited to change this].

Secondly, both ways round are grammatical - but the "to her" is part of the pattern "write a letter to ...", so there is a strong preference for putting it closer to the verb than an adjunct (an optional extra) such as "for two hours".

Comment: Agreed. Note that *"writing a letter for her"* is quite valid but it is equivalent to *"writing a letter on her behalf"*

Comment: Would whoever downvoted this like to indicate why? I'm not bothered about being downvoted per se, but as it stands it has a negative score, which may suggest that it is not useful. If it isn't, I'd like to know why.